# Need help retrieving items in multiple playlists

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Got some code that works just fine and will retrieve all the items in a specified playlist but need to amend it so it can loop through an array of playlists and retrieve all items in each list.

I've tried putting for-next loops in various places in the code but, as my javascript is poor, those efforts have failed and I don't know what to do next.

```
function onGoogleLoad() {
  showhide('hidden');
  getSearchParameters();
  gapi.client.setApiKey(APIKEY);
  gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function () {

    GatherVideos("", function () {
      for (var i = 0; i < allVideos.length; i++) {
        console.log(allVideos[i].snippet.title + " published at " + allVideos[i].snippet.publishedAt)
      }

      showhide('visible');
      build_html(allVideos);
    });

  });
}
ORIGINAL CODE ...


        function GatherVideos(pageToken, finished) {
            var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
                part: 'snippet, contentDetails',
                playlistId: 'UU_FksrzP3q-IuoWTiG501LQ',
                maxResults: 50,
                pageToken: pageToken
            });

            request.execute(function(response) {
                allVideos = allVideos.concat(response.items);
                if (!response.nextPageToken)
                    finished();
                else
                    GatherVideos(response.nextPageToken, finished);
            });
        }
END ORIGINAL CODE

NEW CODE WITH ATTEMPT AT LOOPING ...

        function GatherVideos(pageToken, finished) {
                for (var p=0;p<allPlaylists.length;p++)
                {
                    console.log('Gathering: ' + allPlaylists[p]);
                var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
                 part: 'snippet, contentDetails',
                  playlistId: allPlaylists[p],
                   maxResults: 50,
                    pageToken: pageToken
                });             

                request.execute(function(response) {
                        console.log('Executing: ' + request);               
                   allVideos = allVideos.concat(response.items);
                    if (!response.nextPageToken)
                       finished();
                   else
                    GatherVideos(response.nextPageToken, finished);
                    });
           } //End for loop
        }
END NEW CODE ...

  function build_html(parArray) {
    var n = 0;
    var playlistHtml = '';
    var rows = Math.floor(parArray.length / vinrow);
    var rem = (allVideos.length % vinrow);
    if (rem > 0) {
      rows++;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      playlistHtml += '<div class="row">';

      for (var k = 0; k < vinrow; k++) {
        if (n < parArray.length) {
          playlistHtml += '<div id=' + n + ' class="col item"><img class="img-responsive fit-image" src="' + 
            parArray[n].snippet.thumbnails.default.url + '"><div class="vtitle">' + 
            parArray[n].snippet.title + '</div></div>';

          n++;
        } else {
          playlistHtml += '<div class="col item"><div class="vtitle"> </div></div>';
        }
      }

      playlistHtml += "</div>";
    }

    playlist_div.innerHTML = playlistHtml;
  }
}
```

So, need some help about where to place the code which will loop through the array of playlists.

Comment: Could you add your attempt in the question? Preferably in a separate code block, so the working version isn't cluttered.

Comment: Sure, here it is:         `code` function GatherVideos(pageToken, finished) {
          for (var p=0;p<allPlaylists.length;p++)
          {
           console.log('Gathering: ' + allPlaylists[p]);
             var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
                 part: 'snippet, contentDetails',
                 playlistId: allPlaylists[p],
                 maxResults: 50,
                 pageToken: pageToken
            });          
          }

Comment: You will want to edit your question and put the script not add as a comment. Also the build_html function

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the code formatted properly ... sorry ...

Comment: @user1106252 I'd normally format the code in my preferred editor. After it's to my liking, indent 4 spaces, and copy it into the question.

Comment: One observation is you never declare or set vinrow

Comment: vinrow is declared earlier. I haven't posted the entire javascript code, just the portion that gets the videos. It works just fine with one playlist.

Comment: Think I ballsed the code up earlier whilst copying/pasting but it's ok now.

Comment: @user1106252 There might still be something wrong you're currently never executing `request`. This was present before.

Comment: I've updated the code block to show the original code - which works perfectly for a single playlist - and the 'new' code which is my failed attempt at looping through an array of playlists.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Yes,  i see what you mean ... I've moved the end brace of the for loop so it sits after the request.execute function. Code seems to work for small playlists i.e. where the < 50 items. Still having problems for playlists > 50 items though. Will investigate further and get back later.

Answer (score 0):

You loop over `allPlaylists`, building the request and saving it in the `request` variable. The issue is, that this loops overwrites the `request` variable each time it is executed. When you later call `request.execute(...)` you're only executing the last request build (last playlist in the array).

You should move the request execution inside the *for*-loop.

```
for (var p = 0; p < allPlaylists.length; p++)
{
    console.log('Gathering: ' + allPlaylists[p]);
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({ /* ... */ });
    request.execute(/* ... */);
}
```

The above already fixes part of the issue. **This however doesn't fix the problem in its entirety.** You're recursively calling `GatherVideos` (if there is more than 1 page) which in turn walks through the whole `allPlaylists` array again. Setting out new requests for each playlist.

To resolve the issue above retrieving videos from a single playlist should be moved into its own method. Using with the current structure is a bit cumbersome for different reasons, so I've rebuild it from scratch using a somewhat different approach. This might not be the exact answer you're looking for, but I hope it will give you some inspiration:

```
async function listPlaylist(options = {}) {
    var maxResults, pendingMaxResults, response;

    options = Object.assign({}, options);
    maxResults = options.maxResults;

    if (Number.isInteger(maxResults) && maxResults > 0) {
        // set options.maxResults to a value 1-50
        options.maxResults = (maxResults - 1) % 50 + 1;
        pendingMaxResults = maxResults - options.maxResults;
    } else if (maxResults === "all") {
        pendingMaxResults = "all";
    }

    response = await Promise.resolve(gapi.client.youtube.list(options));

    if (response.nextPageToken && (pendingMaxResults === "all" || pendingMaxResults > 0)) {
        options.maxResults = pendingMaxResults;
        options.pageToken = response.nextPageToken;
        return response.items.concat(await listPlaylist(options));
    } else {
        return response.items;
    }
}

(async function () {
    var playlistsVideos, videos;

    // retrieve all videos of all playlists
    playlistsVideos = await Promise.all(allPlaylists.map(function (playlistId) {
        return listPlaylist({ 
            id: playlistId,
            part: "snippet, contentDetails",
            maxResults: "all"
        });
    }));

    // the above variable `playlistsVideos` is in the format:
    // [[p1v1, p1v2, p1v3], [p2v1, p2v2, p2v3]] (p = playlist, v = video)
    // this needs to be flattened to have the result you want
    videos = playlistsVideos.reduce((videos, playlistVideos) => videos.concat(playlistVideos), []);
})();
```

I'd recommend checking out the guide [Using Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) and checking out the documentation for [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). The above is based upon [YouTube API V3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list). I hope I wrote the code clear enough to let it speak for itself. If you have any question just ask away in the comments.

Comment: That's enormously generous of you, thank you. Your code makes me understand how little I know of javascript! I did spend some of yesterday looking at Promises but struggled to get my head around it. There is much in your code I don't understand though, not least how to integrate it into what I've already got i.e. how does the code get fired? Which is the function to call and where from? How are the playlists passed in ... and many more.  Thanks in advance for your efforts.